How to pass argv to syscall defined in a custom Linux kernel module
In a Linux kernel module, I have defined some syscalls that are called from an external user code. The user code invokes (one of) the syscalls passing to it the first two arguments from command line, i.e. argv[1] and argv[2].
As an example, if I run ./usercode first second, i want first and second to be sent as arguments to the syscall.
I want to check the count of arguments and their validity in kernel-side (i.e., terminating the syscall with an error code if arguments are actually more than 2 or less than 2, argc-like, or if some of the arguments are NULL or somewhat invalid for my purpose) as it is more secure, but I think passing directly the argv array to the syscall would be... a little insecure. What is a good practice to pass these arguments to the syscall? I thought of concatenating them in a string (separated by \0 maybe), but it seems a bit an overkill.
(Obviously, once in kernel mode, copy_from_user() is the first thing I do, for security checks)

Do you know how to pass two strings that aren't elements of argv?

Yes, and it is actually the code I have now (check argc in user, pick the two strings separatedly, pass the to the syscall - defined kernel-side with two parameters as SYSCALL_DEFINEx(2, char*, first, char*, second). The point is that I want to transfer the argc check into the syscall, kernel-side, instead of doing it user-side, so I need to pass all the CLI parameters to syscall

It sounds like user code is where those checks belong.  The kernel code shouldn't care where the source strings originated from, only that it got two arguments of type char *.  Either that, or change the kernel call to accept an int and a char **.

Isn't it possible to make some malicious alterations to the two char* before invoking the syscall? That was the main reason I write this post, alongside the fact that I also have some kernel-side check on euid that must be 0: when that user code is not invoked with sudo I want to return to user -EACCES independently of the argc value (if the argc check is user-side, I cannot do that because the argc check is done before the euid check, and consequently the syscall is not even invoked)

I am not sure what do you mean by "insecure" or "malicious alterations" when pass pointers to the memory inside argv to the system calls. The memory inside argv belongs only to the process, in the same way as e.g. data section of the program. That is, passing argv to the kernel has the same security aspects as passing pointer to the string defined in the program's code.

In other words, there's nothing preventing the program from modifying strings in argv. Many programs actually do this to customize their ps output.
